# database for arabic and english language MVC SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am developing one application where the client wants to see contents in both arabic and english. The displayed data is retrieving from database SQL.

The question here is If the user saves his details in database in english language, how can i show that data in arabic from database?

How can i achieve this part?

Comment: Any text, or just a pre-defined set of words?

Comment: Hire a translator.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a translator API and save both the languages to database.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you can do that without using some sort of translation service, there is nothing in .NET or SQL server (or any other RDBMS that I know of) that will do that for you.

Here's one (API) that is from Microsoft if you need a place to start:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx

Depending on your requirements, you may want to translate data immediately and store it into the opposite database; however it may end up being expensive, so if you're able you might choose to translate things on demand to save some costs.

Answer (score -1):

i think An effective way to create localized Web pages is to use resource objects for your page's text and controls. By using properties placed in resource objects, ASP.NET can select the correct property at run time according to the user's language and culture. The process is straightforward:

[Resource Files and ASP.NET MVC Projects](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/localization-of-a-site-in-mvc5-using-resource-file/)

[fore more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx)

Comment: He's not looking for localization he wants to translate user entered data, things he can't possibly know ahead of time.

Comment: Yes you are right. I want to translate user entered data and show on web page

Comment: So That u have to save the data in in both languages or some service you have to use to change the data from the View